# String.Contains(x) == True but String.IndexOf(x) == -1?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I ran into some malicious requests while parsing log files and found this case where I threw an exception because I try to extract the non-querystring portion of the URL by taking everything up to the "?" if present:

```
string s = @"/adServer/adSer�1X���L) [���0�:�^�?ް�9� �a�d�t��h� I����PA� �1 �G���$�";
string ch = "?";
bool b = s.Contains(ch);
int i = s.IndexOf(ch);
```

But in this case, it contained a "?", but when I tried `.Substring(0, IndexOf("?"))` I got an exception because `IndexOf` was -1. How is this possible?

Here's the actual string in case it doesn't render properly:

[image]

So when this code runs, `b == True`, but `i == -1`.

Interstingly, if I change the code to `char ch = '?'` instead of `string ch = "?"` it works as expected.

Comment: ?ް  is treating as a single character...that is why ? is not found..Try finding ?ް instead of ? in the string ... you will get the index